# Cannot resolve corresponding jni function

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

i read a lot of posts but cannot resolve this yet.

There is my error lines and structure of project: [image: error and structure]

Some libraries and configs I take from another project... And don't know where I went wrong.

I will give you source code of files if needed

[image: tools]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: trying link c++ to project
get this
External Native Build Issues [link](https://pastebin.com/6K1RAuds) 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> executing external native build for ndkBuild D:\android\AndroidStudioProjects\DiceReader\app\src\main\jniLibs\Android.mk

Answer (score 9):

I've also been getting this error since upgrading from Android Studio 2 to  3.  The code compiles, but the IDE isn't recognizing the native functions.  (This may be due to a preprocessor macro I've created that simplifies JNI function names.)

I've suppressed this error in Java by adding `@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")` before my class declaration.

Comment: Same issue here! No way to workaround without changing the code?

Comment: None that I know of.  I had this problem back in Android Studio version 1.  The problem went away in version 2, but reappeared in version 3.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so this missing 'JNI function' isn't a big deal.  I know it's highlighted red, but the function is being linked, just not in a way that the IDE can determine.

First, here's the relevant source code: https://github.com/koreader/crengine/blob/master/android/jni/cr3engine.cpp#L770

CrEngine is linking the functions at run time.  The reason why your IDE isn't picking them up is because the CrEngine functions start with `Java_org_` instead of `Java_com_`.  If you were relying on the engine to automatically link, this would be an issue, but as stated before, they are being explicitly linked at runtime with `jniRegisterNativeMethods`.

---

Do a `clean` and update your build tools to 25.0.3 (or better) in your gradle.build file.  Update your SDKs and NDK.  Then rebuild.  Some of the errors I saw could be caused by older build tools.

Comment: Specifically, I used to get `make: *** No rule to make target 'xxxx', needed by xxx\cp_stats.o'.  Stop.` all the time before updating.  I would have to clean build to fix.